# iPhone Case program

Tags: iphone

It was my understanding that iphone case program closed on 30 September, however I downloaded the app for it anyway, and ordered a case just to see if it would work, and well it let me login (I had the wrong email address entered in so I never got the email telling it been dispatched) and select a case and well it arrived today.

So is the case program still on or is it just luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free case program is valid for iPhone 4s that were purchased before or on September 30, 2010. The customer is required to apply within 30 days of his or her iPhone 4 purchase. This means you will have been able to order a free case after September 30, as long as you purchased your iPhone before or on September 30, and ordered the case within 30 days. You must have had good timing. For customers who purchased an iPhone 4 on September 30, October 30 should be the final day it is possible for them to order a free case via the case program app. However, Apple is still offering to provide users experiencing antenna issues with a free Bumper case if they call AppleCare.

Comment: My iphone was bought last weekend, not in september.

Comment: You just got lucky :)